# Showing response error text when requesting a blob type

Tags: php, xmlhttprequest

I have made a XMLHttpRequest with the 'responseType' set to 'blob' to a php script, is it possible i return more than one type of response? If script can run successfully, response with 'contentType/application/zip' but if the script failed, response with 'string'(error text). I try to response a string in my php script
but, in my javascript, i set the XHR.responseType = 'blob'.

In PHP

```
if(someThingWrong)
{
echo "Archive not found"; //Repsonse is DOMString
header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found"); 
exit;
}
else
{
header("Content-type: application/zip"); //Response is octe-Stream or zip
header("Content-Disposition:  attachment; filename=\"" . basename($newZipFile) . "\"" );
readfile($newZipFile);  
}
```

In Javascript

```
XHR.open("POST", "anycode.php");
XHR.responseType = "blob";
```

When i try to access the xhr.ResponseText, it show 'undefined'.

```
    if(XHR.status == 404) 
    {alert(XHR.ResponseText);}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: its `responseText` with a common `r`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a FileReader object to get the response as text.

```
if(XHR.status == 404){ 
    var fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = function(e){
        alert(e.target.result);
    }
    fr.readAsText(XHR.response);
}
```